# How to move the text marker inside a input field. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Text marker might be the wrong word, I mean the stick/pipe (|) that follows the text you writes and let the user know where the characters will be placed inside a text box

Basically I want to know how to get the text marker and how to move it.

I'm looking for a call like this document.getPipe;

To make it more clear I show a picture on a "text marker".
Image below is on the thing I want to get/call and move inside a input field
[image]

Comment: Hi! It's hard to imagine what is it that you need, please provide [mcve] of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Ok I'll try again.

Comment: @Esko the pipe ( | ) that moves when you type... he want to have 2 buttons which will move the pipe..

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct word which is insertion point.

And to move the insertion point you can use this

```
var input = document.getElementById("inpuName");
var pointYouWantToMoveTo = 1;
input.setSelectionRange(pointYouWantToMoveTo, pointYouWantToMoveTo);
```

This code will move the insertion point to the second character in the input field.
if the text inside the input field is: hello world| it will move here 
h|ello world.